# C# Troubles reading xml value

Tags: c#, regex, xml, double-quotes, slash

I'm trying to read an XML value but I'm having some problems.

This is the string:`""id"":""[0-9]{19}"",""display_src`

This is what I have put in the XML file (because of the doublequotes):

`&quot;&quot;id&quot;&quot;:&quot;&quot;[0-9]{19}&quot;&quot;,&quot;&quot;display_src`

This is the function I wrote for reading the values (works fine with the others):

```
public static string Load()
{
    return XML.SelectSingleNode("Config/Contacts/First).InnerText;
}
```

But when I'm calling it I get this:

```
"\"\"id\"\":\"\"[0-9]{19}\"\",\"\"display_src"
```

Why am I getting those slashes? How can I fix that? Thanks in advance for any answers :)

Comment: You are not 'getting' slashes, only seeing them in a Debug View. Looking for a dupe.

Comment: Those slashes are to escape characters. making `"` as character so the compiler does not take it as end or start of string.

Comment: When you have a string surrounded by double quotes, any double quotes within that string need to be escaped. That changes each of those `"` into `\"`. This is by design.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys, now I get it